# How can I interleave a section of two binary numbers?

Tags: c++, c, bit

I am trying to "merge" two binary integers into one but I can't seem to get it right.

The operation I am trying to do is:

```
Number of bits to merge = 3 (precomputed parameter)

Int 1 : 10010
Int 2 : 11011
```

Given these two numbers, append 3 bit of each to the result (left to right):

```
Result : 11 01 00.
```

Meaning the first bit of the first integer
and the first bit of the second integer. Then the second bit of
the first integer and the second bit of the secod integer... and so on
"Number of bits to merge" times.

Another example with letters would be:

```
Number of bits to merge = 4

Int1: abcde
Int2: xyzwt

Result: ax by cz dw
```

My idea is to use a for loop with the ammount of bits I have to set and there append to the result number, but I don't know how to do that "appending".

Comment: The question is unclear for me. Can you describe it? What do you mean with _"merge"_? What is the _"number of bits to merge"_? Do you mean `(int2 & 0b11100) << 1 | int1 >> 2`?

Comment: I don't understand which bits are merged. Could you [edit] and elaborate? Maybe by representing the bits with letters for example Int1 = abc, Int2 = def, "merged" result = abcdef or whatever

Comment: In that mentioned for loop, let's imagine the result variable is 0000. What should I do to turn the first 0 into the bit value that the first integer has and do the same for the second integer? Sorry if my descriptions are not good enough, english is not my first language. If it is still unclear I will try to rephrase it

Comment: You can use bit manipulation. You can set the fourth bit with `result = result & ~(1 << 3) | int2 & (1 << 3))`

Comment: @Jabberwocky let's see if that second example explains it better

Comment: How do you know where to start taking bits? Is it from the start of the input uint32_t / uint8_t?

Comment: What would be the result of: Number of bits to merge = 2, Int1 = 0011, Int2 = 0101? What's the type of Int1 and Int2? Are they strings? Can they have leading zeros? Do Int1 and Int2 have the same length?

Comment: @Botje the question is a simplified example of a more complex problem. The input is an int (c++ mvsc size). Let's say the starting point is a given parameter

Comment: @ThomasSablik Result would be = 0001. The type of Int1 and Int2 are Int, and result is a uint32_t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set each bit in a loop:

```
std::uint32_t merge(std::size_t start, std::size_t numberOfBits, int i1, int i2) {
    if (start == 0 || start > sizeof(int) * 8) return 0;
    if (numberOfBits == 0 || numberOfBits > 16) return 0;
    if (start < numberOfBits) return 0;
    
    int result = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numberOfBits; ++i) {
        std::size_t srcPos = start - 1 - i;
        std::size_t destPos = 2 * (numberOfBits - i) - 1;
        result |= (i1 & (1 << srcPos)) >> srcPos << destPos;
        result |= (i2 & (1 << srcPos)) >> srcPos << (destPos - 1);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::size_t start = 5;
    std::size_t numberOfBits = 3;
    int i1 = 0b10010;
    int i2 = 0b11011;
    return merge(start, numberOfBits, i1, i2);
}
```

`i1 & (1 << (start - 1 - i))` reads the i-th bit from left. `>> (start - 1 - i)` shifts it to the right. `<< (2 * (numberOfBits - i) - 1)` resp. `<< (2 * (numberOfBits - i) - 2)` shifts it to the correct position in the result.

Tested with input:

```
Start : 5
Number of bits : 3
Int 1 : 0b10010
Int 2 : 0b11011
```

output:

```
52 // == 0b110100
```

and input:

```
Start : 4
Number of bits : 2
Int 1 : 0b1010
Int 2 : 0b0101
```

output:

```
9 // == 0b1001
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a bit mask, used to select which and how many bits to keep:

```
int mask = (1 << 3) - 1;    // results in 0000 0000 0000 0111
```

Next you have to think about which bit locations you want from each input integer, I will call them i1 and i2:

```
// i1 = 0000 0000 0001 0010
// i2 = 0000 0000 0001 1011
int mask_shifted = mask << 3; // results in 0000 0000 0011 1000
```

Now you can apply the masks to the ints and merge the result with bit operations:

```
int applied_i1 = i1 & mask_i1; // results in 0000 0000 0001 0000
int applied_i2 = i2 & mask_i2; // results in 0000 0000 0001 1000
int result = (applied_i2 << 1) | (applied_i1 >> 3); // results in 0000 0000 0011 0100
```

Comment: OP wants to interleave bits from each masked segment, not concatenate them.

Comment: This answer I think would also work, but the selected one goes more with what I was planning on doing. Thanks anyway!